# Movie with "hero" jumping from a bridge in a condor-like suit

Tags: super-hero

I remember watching a film ~20 years ago (this film may have been older that that) where there was a hero who used a **suit** resembling a **hawk or a condor**. I can only remember two scenes:

- The first when he jumped from a bridge using this bird suit and flies.
- The second is a car chase when he is pursuing/being pursued by a group of black cars (I think they were Porsches). When this hero makes a back turn and faces the black cars chasing him he pushes a button and his car converts into a ramp so the Porsches jump into the air, crash land and the hero comes out victorious.

Does anybody have a clue about his film? This has been bothering me for years, I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: You guys are awesome, that's it, it's condorman [Condorman](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAtervTgpys)

Comment: Excellent description. The only thing that marred it for me is that a 2-second google would have answered it for you :-)

Comment: I tried "hero + condor/hawk" and "car chase + porsche" but never condorman :) 

As I said, now and then I've been looking for this one for several years without any look but finally I can rest in peace. Thank you again guys.

Comment: "finally I can rest in peace" - damn dude, you okay?

Comment: So it's about a MAN who may dress as a CONDOR ... I wonder what the film could be called ... ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has GOT to be [Condorman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082199/). It's an excellent movie about a cartoonist who is recruited by a spy agency who then builds all the gadgets from his cartoon for him to use in real life.

It has the suit, it has the group of black Porsches.  It's really hard to get ahold of since it is rather obscure.

Comment: DAMN IT! I always knew someone was bound to ask about Condor Man, and I was always ready to answer. Good work!

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if you can remember any other details, but the hawk/condor suit made me immediately thing of [Condorman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorman).

[image: Condorman]

Comment: Crikey. The image I had in my head of this film from the OP's description was somewhat cooler than this.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It's actually a fun movie which doesn't take itself too seriously, so you shouldn't :)

Comment: @SystemDown: oh absolutely, I agree. It's just I was imagining something like [the gliding bit in *After Earth*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-Ng2GlGIy0&t=1m30s).

Comment: I can find a slightly less crappy image if you'd like